# Google Gadget api deprecated?

Tags: google-maps, google-gadget

I need to create google gadgets and put it into google site. Does anyone know if google gadget still supported by google? Because I am triyng to create "Hello World" gadgets it doesn't work. I can't found "google gadget editor" as well. If it doesn't support anymore, is there any alternative?

Regards

Comment: they do work. we cant help unless you show the code and specific error.

Comment: Hi, as I know from this site [link](http://siteshelp.kccloudsolutions.com/step-by-step-guides/buildinggadgetsforgooglesites), there is a google gadget editor where I can build, hosting and manage my gadget. Where I can find this?

Comment: i dont think its available. gadgets is super old tech that will likely deprecate.

Answer (score 3):

The [Legacy Gadgets API](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/devguide_landing) is the deprecated version and was replaced by the **gadgets.* API**

Use [gadgets.* API](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/) for all gadget development, regardless of whether you are developing regular gadgets or OpenSocial gadgets.

Comment: Does that gadgets.* API page render OK for you? It looks buggy to me on chrome 50.0.2661.102 m

Comment: I don't see anything wrong on my side and I'm using Chrome too. What do you mean buggy?

Comment: It looks like css issues with text overlapping each other etc. making it difficult to read.

Comment: I remembered encountering that problem when I had slow network connectivity issue. Otherwise, please try https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/113910?hl=en